# Best condition to defend against race condition entering SQL commands using Monitor statements

Tags: c#

I have a problem of two requests entering the same code simulataneously. I implemented the following solution that I read in the following article: https://www.developerfusion.com/article/84514/deep-c-8211-avoiding-race-conditions/

Code:

```
public class TransactionManager
{
    static readonly object MyCountLock = new object();

    public void ExectuteSQLStatments() 
    {
        try
        {
            Monitor.Enter(MyCountLock);

            // SQL statements that must be executed by one thread (or entering SQL).
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(MyCountLock);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure that it is the best way to protect the execution of the statements by only one thread entering the 'Monitor' statement. That code was affected recently by race condition recently, and I want to prevent that condition from happening again.

Comment: Sounds great. What is your question ? What does 'best condition' mean ?

Comment: You could as well use `lock(MyCountLock){...}`. See [lock statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve. If it is database locks that you are trying to achieve, there are multiple ways to do it.

1. Perfectly good example, the way you did it is just fine. Though this does not protect your database from deadlocks. If there is another piece of code that handles the same tables, then it could be that you'll still get to the deadlocked situation.
2. You can also use locks, [check difference with Monitor here](https://www.interviewsansar.com/2016/06/23/monitor-vs-lock-in-csharp-why-use-monitor-instead-of-lock/).
3. You can lock with the database itself.  Aquire a lock to the table that you fear can be deadlock before anything. You can do this by doing a mock update (update to the same value) of the rows you want to change. That way the next command will wait for you to commit the transaction before being able to start. This has the added value that you can update other rows that are not used in the same transactions.

As always, it depends on what you want to achieve. Provide some extra information and code for more help on this.